# Which framework do you use for building your applications?

Tags: frameworks, survey

There are a number of framework out there that provide the skeleton for building applications such as [CSLA](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/), [XAF](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/), [SCSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480482.aspx), ...

Do you use one yourself or do you build from scratch?

Comment: Make it a community wiki

Answer (score 4):

.NET is my favorite framework.

The applications I work on are usually too complex to fit into a "skeleton". However when working on Winforms, I like to take advantage of [CAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) for the UI. I wouldn't say this is the skeleton, but more or less the ground work for which the skeleton can be built, then the meat can be built upon it. I also like using a MVC for connecting the UI to the Data Layer. The Data Layer is typically LLBLGen or nHibernate.

For generating your skeleton for web applications, the [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/) framework looks really promising.

Answer (score 2):

I just use my own class library, which handles things like SQL (differences between different engines), provides lots of custom data structures and types, IoC/Dependency injection, etc.

I have been using the XPO-library from DevExpress before but after having some rather largish performance problems with it I'm back to plain SQL.

I have never used a bigger framework like those you mention. Earlier experience with those have always led me to believe they're powerful, but also restricting. You usually end up combating the way they do things to implement more complex features.

Answer (score 2):

I used CSLA.NET to build an large LOB Windows application (title insurance) in 2007, basically it is a framework that you build your business objects based on. The business objects are generated from database tables with predefined templates. SPs are mostly utilized for data access. Personally I've not liked it because there are lots of code and template need to maintain, I prefer ORM to template based approach.

I've been using XAF to build another Windows based HR application, it can help you create a complete application just in 15 minutes with nice UI and lots of cool stuffs such at localization, customization, skinable and so on. But the big problems with XAF are limitation of the underlying XPO, and not so good performance.